# Factory Reset (micro)SD Card

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, sd-card

This is not similar to other questions on this site.

I used WinImage to restore a virtual hard disk to a physical drive. This was so I could make a backup of my Nook. It created a partition of around 76MB on the SD card.
Afterwards I wanted to use this SD card for something else but I don't know how I can reclaim the original 2GB of this SD card. I tried reformatting using the official Windows program and with Minitool Partition Wizard and even with the official SDFormatter program. All it will allow me to do is reformat (wipe) that 76MB partition. I'm afraid I've done something stupid and lost the whole card in the process.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In the SDFormatter tool click Options and choose *Format size adjustment: On*. This should format the card without taking current filesystem into consideration and reclaim all available space.